# How can knative functions react to multiple URL paths?

Tags: knative, knative-serving

I have created a simple hello-world function via `func create -l go` and can successfully run it locally and have it deployed in k8s.

The function is not invoked if I call `http://localhost:8080/some-random-path`.

I suspect there is an option to configure this in the `func.yml`? I have not yet found any reference or documentation about this topic on the knative documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

The current implementation in https://github.com/boson-project/buildpacks/blob/main/buildpacks/go/faas/main.go#L82 appears to use `gorilla/mux`'s `Router.Handle`, which defines an exact match on `/`.

Different function implementations may define different HTTP serving semantics (some might only allow POST, others might allow only specific URLs); you could also file an issue at http://GitHub.com/knative/func/issues/new requesting a change in the behavior along with your use case.

Comment: Ah, i guess this is one important clue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation generated alongside the `func`'s `go` template](https://github.com/knative/func/blob/main/docs/function-templates/golang.md#function-reference), it looks like a Go HTTP function has access to a [standard `http.Request`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) as the second or third parameter, which includes a `URL` field.  You could use this to implement your own `mux`.

Comment: To me it seems that any requests with a path != "" do not really reach the knative function. That is the first thing that would have to work. I do not mind creating / using a simple muxer. The 404 i receive does not seem to come from my function but the knative routing instead.

Comment: Your observations are correct. I'd missed that the framework uses `gorilla/mux`, which (unlike `http.ServeMux`) defines an exact path match semantic, which is used here: https://github.com/boson-project/buildpacks/blob/main/buildpacks/go/faas/main.go#L82